# How to check if strings are surrounded by spaces

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string pattern in Python:

```
{{test1 | test2(a) | test3|test4}}
```

I want to check if the string contains sub-strings which are not separated by a space before/after the pipe (|).

So in this example following sub-strings should be "marked" as not valid:

- test3 (missing space before |)
- test4 (missing space after |)

I tried this with a regex `(?<=\|)(\S*?)(?=\|)` but had no luck

Comment: *I tried this with a regex* – please show your attempt.

Comment: Tried multiple things and don't remember all. Last try was  `(?<=\|)(\S*?)(?=\|)`

Comment: You don't need a regex, you could just `split` the string on `|` and check if the parts start/end with a space. You haven't specified what you should do around the brackets (are spaces there allowed/possible...), you should make that clear also.

Comment: Might be a bit slow, but `(?<=\|)[^{}\s]+|[^{}\s]+(?=\|)` works.

Comment: After/before the brackets spaces are not required. If I simply split, I have to find a way to decide if the string is between | or started/ends with bracktes...

Comment: @Sweeper yes it works, thanks

Comment: @Sweeper was working on something like that but does not work for three consecutive mistakes like `test3|test4|test5` it will return `test3|test4` and `test5`

Comment: @HadiFarah Adding `|` into the inverse character class solves the problem, I think. `(?<=\|)[^{}\s|]+|[^{}\s|]+(?=\|)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this regex should work:

```
(?<=\|)[^{}\s|]+|[^{}\s|]+(?=\|)
```

There are two cases:

- `(?<=\|)[^{}\s|]+` for anything that has no leading space (no space after |)

  - `(?<=\|)` looks behind for a '|'
  - `[^{}\s|]+` matches the text you want. (Any character that is not a whitespace, '|', or bracket)
- `[^{}\s|]+(?=\|)` for any thing that has no trailing space (no space before |)

  - `[^{}\s|]+` matches the text you want.
  - `(?=\|)` looks ahead for a '|'

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3Vbszn/1)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can make a loop to check.

```
for(i=0, i < str.length, i++){
    value1 = str[i];
    value2 = str[i+1];
    value3 = str[i+2];
    if(value2 == '|'){
        if(value1 == ' '){
            // do what you want do here
        }else{}
        if(value3 == ' '){
            // do what you want do here
        }else{}
    }
}
```